# How to find the streak using email ids in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has students and the days they have attended their classes

```
Email             Day
mala@gmail.com     1
vika@gmail.com     1
rupa@gmail.com     1
vika@gmail.com     2
vika@gmail.com     3
rupa@gmail.com     3
```

Expected Output:

```
Email                 Streak
mala@gmail.com          1
rupa@gmail.com          1
vika@gmail.com          3
```

The result must be in such a way that only those who attended the classes in a streak like day1,day2,day3 must be printed

How can I do this using pandas?

Comment: Do you mean it should be consecutive days?

Comment: yes ishwar it can also by day1,day2 / day2,day3 but it should not be day1 and day3 . I dont want to know the count of emails i want to find only those tht are consecutive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way that returns the length of the longest consecutive streak within each `'Email'`.

First `drop_duplicates` that way repeated days for the same e-mail don't ruin any streaks, and sort. Then create labels for groups of consecutive days taking the cumsum of where the difference in days is not equal to `1`. Finally group by the `'Email'` and this group label and find the max size.

For clarity, I added an additional group at the end which has a streak of three on days 5,6,7.

```
print(df)

Email             Day
mala@gmail.com     1
vika@gmail.com     1
rupa@gmail.com     1
vika@gmail.com     2
vika@gmail.com     3
rupa@gmail.com     3
foo@gmail.com      1
foo@gmail.com      5
foo@gmail.com      6
foo@gmail.com      7
```

---

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['Email', 'Day']).sort_values(['Email', 'Day'])
s1 = df1.groupby('Email').Day.diff().ne(1).cumsum()

df1.groupby(['Email', s1]).size().groupby('Email').max()
```

---

```
Email
foo@gmail.com     3
mala@gmail.com    1
rupa@gmail.com    1
vika@gmail.com    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your requirement correctly we can use a `groupby.diff` and `.loc` to filter your values.

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Email')['Day'].diff().fillna(1).eq(1)].groupby('Email')['Day'].idxmax()


df1 = df.loc[idx]


            Email  Day
0  mala@gmail.com    1
2  rupa@gmail.com    1
4  vika@gmail.com    3
```

---

stepping through each part of the code :

```
df.groupby('Email')['Day'].diff().fillna(1)

0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    2.0 # < -- we don't want this. 
Name: Day, dtype: float64
```

Of the above values, we want the max day grouped by email returned as an index value.

```
print(idx)

Email
mala@gmail.com    0 
rupa@gmail.com    2
vika@gmail.com    4
Name: Day, dtype: int64


            Email  Day
0  mala@gmail.com    1 # this row.
1  vika@gmail.com    1
2  rupa@gmail.com    1 # this row.
3  vika@gmail.com    2
4  vika@gmail.com    3
5  rupa@gmail.com    3 # this row.
```

if you want to filter out anyone who has no streaks, as in their greatest streak is one day, you could use

```
df.duplicated(subset=['Email'],keep=False)
```